# Primary difference between FDR and Nixon for de-linking gold with dollar?

Tags: gold-standard

I'm unable to understand the different role that both FDR and Nixon, played in de-linking gold with dollar.

I do understand that after Nixon, value of dollar is not linked to amount of gold (No longer fixed exchange rate between gold and dollar). But how did both FDR and Nixon both play two different roles?

Comment: ...by the role of FDR, do you mean the Bretton Woods agreement?

Comment: Yes. How did both differ?

Comment: The Bretton Woods system was created during FDR, ended under Nixon? I am sorry, I do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: Both FDR and Nixon, took steps to take US off from gold standard. Wondering, what are the primary differences in their approach?